# Backpropagation in mini-batch stochastic gradient descent with mean squared error loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, mse, stochastic-gradient-descent

Suppose I have an ANN which has one input layer of size $128$, one hidden layer of size $64$ and one output layer of size $10$ for a classification problem. Let's assume we have a training sample of $1000$ vectors of size $128$.

Suppose I want to use the mean squared error loss (I know this is not the best loss for a classification problem but I just want to use it for the sake of understanding) and I want to do vanilla stochastic gradient descent using backpropagation to update the weights.

During an weight update inside an epoch I draw a single vector (input matrix of size $1\times128$) which will have outputs $o_i$ and actual targets $y_i$, $i=1, \dots, 10$. So my loss function is $$L=\frac{1}{10}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{10}(o_i-y_i)^2.$$ Then for updating a weight, say $w_{mn}$, with backpropagation, I need to compute $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{mn}}$. Since $\frac{\partial (o_j-y_1)^2}{\partial o_1}=0$ for $j\neq1$, we have $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{mn}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_1}\frac{\partial o_1}{\partial w_{mn}}=\frac{1}{10}\frac{\partial (o_1-y_1)^2}{\partial o_1}\frac{\partial o_1}{\partial w_{mn}}=\dots.$$

So far so good, but now suppose I want to do mini-batch stochastic gradient descent and use backpropagation to update the  weights. Suppose the batches are of size $n$.

During an weight update inside an epoch I draw a sample of $n$ vectors of size $128$ (input matrix of size $n\times128$), which will have outputs $o_{ij}$ and targets $y_{ij}$, for $i=1,…,n, j=1, \dots 10$. Again, I want to use the mean squared error loss. Here come my questions:

$(1)$ Will my loss function be $L_i=\frac{1}{10}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{10}(o_{ij}-y_{ij})^2$ for each single vector $i$ in my batch, from which I compute $\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial w_{mn}}$ using backpropagation as above and then I compute the weight update for $w_{mn}$ as $\frac{1}{n} {\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}} \frac{\partial L_i}{\partial w_{mn}}$? This seems to be the case following [backpropagation section of code here for example](https://towardsdatascience.com/backpropagation-from-scratch-on-mini-batches-e6efdaa281a2). What I don't like about this is that it doesn't seem to be right in the way of defining the loss function $L_i$ for each input in the batch, instead of a well defined loss function for the entire batch.

$(2)$ Addressing what I don't like about $(1)$, will the loss function be as [suggested here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11675) $$ L=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{10}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{10}(o_{ij}-y_{ij})^2?$$

But the when I want to compute the weight update for $w_{mn}$, I can do $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{mn}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_{11}}\frac{\partial o_{11}}{\partial w_{mn}}=\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial (o_{11}-y_{11})^2}{\partial o_{11}}\frac{\partial o_{11}}{\partial w_{mn}}=\dots,$$ since $\frac{\partial (o_{ij}-y_{ij})^2}{\partial o_{11}}=0$ for $i\neq1$ and $j\neq1$. But this doesn't seem right as this implies only one vector (with $i,j=1$) out of the $n$ in the batch will contribute to the weight update. So what am I missing?

I would like to know if my general understanding is good and in particular what am I missing in case $(2)$.

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) This is correct because the total loss function is
$$L=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n L_i$$
This is even sometimes defined as the sum of losses, not the average. Differentiation simply spreads over the sum/average.

(2) You have a mistake in differentiation (in single sample case as well). If you have a function $f(x,y)$ and you want to differentiate $f$ wrt another variable $t$, the chain rule is as follows:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Using this, your chain rule for the single sample case should have been written as follows:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{mn}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial w_{mn}}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{10}\frac{\partial (o_i-y_i)^2}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial w_{mn}}$$

because $L$ is a function of $o_i$, $i\in \{1,2...10\}$. So, you can't get away with only $o_1$.

If you reflect this into the mini-batch formula, you can't get away with only $o_{11}$ either. The differentiation should include all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! So $(1)$ and $(2)$ are actually equivalent, or even the same thing. I guess form $(1)$ is preferred in implementations because it's somewhat easier to see what's going on in terms of differentiation.

Comment: Sorry to insist on this, I completely agree with what you said about the use of chain rule, but for eample looking here http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5740/2016sp/resources/backprop.pdf at equations $(8)$ and $(10)$ on pages 5-6, they seem to apply the wrong chain rule formula. Is it a mistake in the notes?

Comment: It's the same principle. There, you have $y_j=f(x_j)$ and $x_j=\sum w_{kj}y'_k$ in Figure 3. Some "cross"-derivatives are $0$, that's why it's more simpler. For example, derivative of $y_j$ wrt $x_i$ is $0$ for i != j. That simplifies the partial derivative sum. But, you can't choose an arbitrary output like in your calculations.